# smart gwt image upload

Tags: gwt, file-upload, smartgwt

Is there a way to upload an image to the server using smart gwt? I noticed there isn't an image upload widget. Does anyone know of some open source code I could use to do this. Right now I'm using a regular upload form, that forces the page to reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Smart does provide this functionality [Upload](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Upload.html).

The key is to use a hidden iframe page as the target so your app does not get reloaded.

[This blog post](http://maryniuk.blogspot.com/2009/09/upload-file-in-smartgwt.html) seems to cover it.

For the JSNI on you hidden page in your app want something like:

```
public static native void uploadComplete() /*-{
  $wnd.alert('Upload Complete');
}-*/;
```

Then on the hidden page specify in the body onLoad

```
window.parent.UploadComplete();
```

Comment: This is actually the part that I need help with. The docs say: In order receive a callback notification when the upload completes, after processing the file upload, your server should output HTML content for the IFRAME that includes a <SCRIPT> block which will navigate out of the IFRAME (generally via the JavaScript global "top") and call a global method you have declared as a callback. Does anyone have some sample javascript code that can do this?